# Specman e: "keep type .. is a" fails to refine the type of a field

Tags: specman, e

I have the next code in my verification environment:

```
// seq_file.e
extend SPECIFIC_TYPE sequence {
    keep type driver is a SPECIFIC_TYPE sequence_driver;
    event some_event is @driver.as_a(SPECIFIC_TYPE sequence_driver).some_event;
};

extend SPECIFIC_TYPE SEQ_NAME sequence {
   body()@driver.clock is only {
      var foo := driver.specific_type_field;
   };
};
```

Note that thank to `keep type driver is a..` there is no need in `driver`'s casting in the line starting `var foo..`

**BUT**, the `keep type driver is a..` does not affect the `some_event`, i.e. if the `as_a` casting is removed from the line, there is a compilation error says `'driver' does not have 'some_event' though its subtype do. use driver.as_a(SPECIFIC_TYPE sequence_driver)`.

Why the `keep type driver is a..` fails to cast the `driver` in `some_event..` line?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct: type constraint is taken into account for a field access (and for a method call), but not for event sampling. This is a limitation, and it might be removed in upcoming versions. I suggest contacting official Specman support for the exact info on the plans.